# Upload word file with cfinder integrated into ckeditor

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, ckfinder

Is there a posibility to upload a file with ckfinder when integrated into ckeditor? I'm trying to upload a word document and insert the link into the text that is currently edited in ckeditor, but i can only upload images and flash files. Is there a way to browse the server and upload any files without placing another ckfinder control for the upload of non-embeddable files?

I am using it on a 2.0 asp.net page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the link dialog, it should have a browse server button if you have integrated CKFinder correctly.